# Print the output of a text without '/n' delimiter

Tags: python

I have the following binary strings

```
In [32]: print(codes)
['01000011', '01101111', '01101101', '01110000', '01110101', '01110100', '01100101', '01110010', '00100000', '01010011', '01100011', '01101001', '01100101', '01101110', '01100011', '01100101']
```

decode them as

```
In [33]: for c in codes:
    ...:     print(chr(int(c, 2)))
    ...:     
C
o
m
p
u
t
e
r

S
c
i
e
n
c
e
```

The text is printed with an implicit '/n',

How could print the output in one line?

Answer (score 2):

```
 codes = ['01000011', '01101111', '01101101', '01110000', '01110101', '01110100', '01100101', '01110010', '00100000', '01010011', '01100011', '01101001', '01100101', '01101110', '01100011', '01100101']

    print codes

    test = ''
    for c in codes:
         test += (chr(int(c,2)))

    print test
```

Comment: `print(chr(int(c,2), end='')`